# Critografia em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, criptografia

Acabei de entrar na área de programação e minha faculdade acabou aplicando um trabalho que teremos que criar um programa em Python que possa efetuar a criptografia/descriptografia de qualquer mensagem, cifrada ou não.

> O programa deverá contemplar a possibilidade de cifragem de frases
> completas até o limite de 128 caracteres, e a sua respectiva
> descriptografia. O programa deverá fazer uso de uma chave
> criptográfica. O nível de refinamento, funcionalidade, tratamento de
> erros e funções extras implementadas neste sistema, assim como o nível
> de complexidade da técnica criptográfica escolhida, terá impacto
> direto na nota final deste.

Baseado nessas informações eu gostaria de pedir ajuda de todos.

Qual criptografia me recomendam para usar como base? Poderiam me recomendar lugares para aprender a como criar um bom programa?

Desde já fico grato!

Comment: Você pode usar bibliotecas prontas? Tem que elaborar seu próprio método de encriptação? O que você já pesquisou?

Answer (score 0):

O python tem uma biblioteca padrão instalada chamada [base64](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/base64.html#module-base64) que tem funções para codificar dados binários em uma sequência de caracteres. Não é exatamente uma criptografia (ao pé da letra), mas pode funcionar para cifrar uma mensagem.

Exemplo:

```
import base64

# codificando a mensagem

mensagemCodificada = base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')
# o 'b' antes da string é para transformá-la em binário.

print(mensagemCodificada)
resultado: b'ZGF0YSB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVk'

# Decodificando a mensagem

mensagemLegivel = base64.b64decode(mensagemCodificada)

print(mensagemLegivel)
resultado: b'Uma mensagem a ser cifrada'
```

Mais uma vez, isso é apenas uma maneira de **cifrar** uma mensagem.
Deixo como sugestão este [link](https://medium.com/curso-de-programacao-python/criptografia-com-fermet-no-python-7008d0c614bf) sobre Criptografia Simétrica usando python.